# How to add \lstlistoflistings to the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

can someone tell me, how to create an entry for the `\lstlistoflistings` command in the TOC? I want, that you can see the page number where the list can be found.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: I use \documentclass{scrreprt}

Answer (score 16):

The solution depends on your documentclass. If you are using a KOMA-class you can use the option `listof`. Of course you can set this key local to `\lstlistoflistings`

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\section{foo}
text
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
(Listing content)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the standard classes the standard command `\addcontentsline` should be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\section{foo}
text
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
(Listing content)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but how do I get the listings entry without numbering?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer: Which number do you mean?

Comment: You can also use chapter instead of section: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}`

Answer (score 7):

For the case anyone uses the tocbibind package, which main purpose is the handling of "list of tables/figures/etc." in the Table of Contents, the documentation already provides a solution:

> There are packages, such as listings and ccaption, that provide new
> Listof lists. These can be handled by the tocbibind package in a
> similar manner to the usual Listofs. Two examples are given below.
> The listings package version 0.2 provides a `\lstlistoflistings`
> command to print a list of listings. The header name for this list is
> in `\lstlistingname` and the listing file has the extension lol. This
> can be treated just like the `\listoffigure`, etc., commands. To add
> the List of Listings header to the ToC do:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\begingroup
>   \tocfile{\lstlistingname}{lol}
> \endgroup}
> ```

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf

There is a mistake in the documentation however, as `\lstlistingname` is the title used for the listings themselves rather than the list of listings which uses `\lstlistlistingname`. So, the correct addition would be:

```tex
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{\begingroup
  \tocfile{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\endgroup}
```

Comment: Remember to still call `\lstlistoflistings` at the desired location of the list of listings in your document, otherwise, nothing will happen.